# Android xml in app cannot find custom view in module

Tags: android, xml, module

Sorry for the dumb question, I'm doing one module for many app.

I create a custom view class in the my module (`public class CustomView extends FrameLayout`).

I have imported this modules into app and class in the app can call my custom view, but xml cannot call my custom view (`compile project(':mymodule')`).

I have not found a solution, thank all the help.

Comment: How are you calling that `Custom View` in xml??

Comment: In Android Studio I press Ctrl + Space, it not show CustomView suggest, I also tried com.modulepackage.CustomView

Comment: giving the full path should be fine as you are doing. Can you do this in any class file and check if that `CustomView` is importing.

Comment: `import com.vtm.advertise.VtmAdView;` my app class are imported this class, but xml is not

Comment: I want to say, can you verify that module is compiled properly by creating a reference of `CustomView` (CustomView customView; in any java file should not give any error)

Comment: `VtmAdView vtmAdView = new VtmAdView(MainActivity.this);` and it auto generate `import com.vtm.advertise.VtmAdView;` without error, but I still cannot call in xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your module gradle has a same compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion as your app gradle. Also it might be beneficial to ensure that you are using same support libraries.
if compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion is set properly you should not have any issues to find you custom view in your xml file (in case if you did not, try to use you application context in xml)